# How to spend the 50 platinum? Can I get more?

Tags: warframe

I've just started playing WarFrame and as usual in free-to-pay games there is some currency that you can buy for real money - platinum - of which I got 50 from start and I probably won't get more soon(without paying real money).

---

**My question is:**

What are the **options** of spending exactly those 50 platinum for person who just started playing the game or would you recommend keeping it for later use and why?

---

Also I've heard that I can get more platinum by trading stuff but is this only via the trade channel or are there any auctions etc? Or can I get any platinum from selling stuff to NPC/world/game?

*I hope reformatting the question made it less opinion-based and it didn't make any of the current answers non-related.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For most players, 50 plat is best spent on:

- 2 Warframe slots

  - 20p each, 40p total

  **or**
- 8 Weapon slots

  - 12p for 2, 48p total.

  **or**
- 1 Warframe slot

  - 20p each, 20p total

  **AND**
- 4 Weapon slots

  - 12p for 2, 24p total.

It all depends on what you'd like to get the most out of. Since there is a wide variety of guns in game some players opt for the weapon slots, while most others might opt for Warframe slots since those are your "classes" so to speak.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I will go for the balanced option(1WF + 4 wep). I already know I want at least 2(3) more warframes to get right now - asap. But I guess it will take me quite while to get Ivara from what I've heard so 3 WF should be enough for start.

Answer (score 3):

The general best use for platinum is to unlock spots for storing warframes/weapons. You can get some free platinum from daily rolls if you get lucky. The other way to get platinum is to trade rare mods, prime blueprints, kubrow imprints and a few other things for it to other players. As of now there is no auction house, so you will need to find people in the Trading channel. See [here](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Trade_System) for more info on trading.

Answer (score 1):

> Also I've heard that I can get more platinum by trading stuff but is this only via the trade channel or are there any auctions etc? Or can I get any platinum from selling stuff to NPC/world/game?

There are two options:

1. You can buy platinum with real money from the Warframe [store](https://www.warframe.com/buyplatinum) or you can 
   buy *Downloadable Content* from [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/230410/Warframe/): Some DLCs contain an amount of platinum.
2. You can trade with other players to earn platinum. To complete a trade you have to meet with the other player either in a [Clan Dojo](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Dojo) or at [Maroo's Bazaar](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Maroo%27s_Bazaar). You can find trading partners either in *Trade Chat* or on 3rd party web sites, like [Warframe Market](http://warframe.market/), or do price checks at [NexusStats](https://nexus-stats.com/). Refer to [this page](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Trade_System) about what items can be traded.

You can **not** get platinum from selling stuff to NPCs or the game.

However you can sell items from your inventory for *credits*. But if you sell weapons or warframes to reclaim free slots then make sure you really don't want them anymore. Also at least level them up to level 30 first to get all the [mastery XP](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Mastery_Rank).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you stop playing for a long time you will have 50 plat again, i had something about 150 platinium to spend

And its good to spend platinum on warframe and weapon slots, maybe orokin catalyst or reactor but only on weapons that you are sure you will keep and are not just another mastery fodder